# $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}|a_{n}-a_{n+1}| $ converges $\Rightarrow \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_{n}z^{n}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

Let $\{a\}_{n} \subset \mathbb{C}$ , $a_{n} \rightarrow 0 $ , $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}|a_{n}-a_{n+1}| < +\infty$; then show that $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_{n}z^{n}$ converges if $|z|\le 1 \ $ , $z \ne 1$.

Furthermore the convergence is uniform in $\{ |z|\le 1 , |z-1|\ge \delta\} \ $ with $\delta > 0 $ sufficiently small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$\begin{align}
\left\lvert(1-z) \sum_{n=k}^m a_n z^n\right\rvert &= \left\lvert\sum_{n=k}^m a_n z^n - \sum_{n=k+1}^{m+1}a_{n-1} z^{n}\right\rvert\\
&= \left\lvert \sum_{n=k+1}^{m} (a_n-a_{n-1})z^n + a_kz^k - a_mz^{m+1}\right\rvert\\
&\leqslant \sum_{n=k+1}^m \left\lvert a_{n}-a_{n-1}\right\rvert + \lvert a_k\rvert + \lvert a_m\rvert.
\end{align}$$

Since by assumption $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lvert a_n - a_{n-1}\rvert < \infty$, and $a_n \to 0$, for any given $\varepsilon > 0$, we can choose a $K\in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$\left\lvert(1-z) \sum_{n=k}^m a_n z^n\right\rvert < \varepsilon$$

for all $k \geqslant K$ and all $m \geqslant k$.

Choose $\varepsilon = \varepsilon_0/\delta$ for the uniform convergence.